# Need certain coordinates to show on Mapview on center MKCoordinateRegion setRegion

Tags: swift, mapkit

I get coordinates from another source and I want to display those coordinates as the center of my map. However, it always crashes. How do I make it valid? I converted it to a double, tried other solutions on stackoverflow, but they seem outdated.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region <center:-121.90043000, +37.32721300 span:+0.02000000, +0.02000000>'
```

```
let viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: station.location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: station.location.coordinate.longitude), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02))
mapView.setRegion(viewRegion, animated: true)
```

Comment: What does "I get that my coordinates need to be within 90" mean?

Comment: A latitude must be between 0 and 90.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance` I used the code below for a similar case as yours

```
func centerMapOnUserLocation() {
    guard let coordinate = locationManager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    let coordinatRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
    mapView.setRegion(coordinatRegion, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: XCode doesn't let me do that

Comment: you can try restarting Xcode... if the problem continues show us the error together with Xcode and swift version you are using

Comment: 'MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance' has been replaced by 'MKCoordinateRegion.init(center:latitudinalMeters:longitudinalMeters:)' Im using swift 4

Comment: replace **MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance** in the function above with `let coordinatRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02))
` this should work if not use directly let coordinatRegion = `MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02))`

Comment: Nope :( same error with libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: google the error nicely I saw some similar answers also check your debug console for some clues